# How to change the color of spinner and its arrow in android studio

Tags: android

I want to add a color to the spinner as well as a color to the arrow of spinner how do I do this in android studio without adding a dependency

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this, Create a new xml `spinner_style.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

And fix this layout as your spinner style in your activity:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_style, gender_spinner);
```